# Rescaling the sum of 3 variables in R to equal exactly 1

Tags: r, rescale

I have a dataframe as below where there are 3 columns, each representing a proportion of time spent in a singlular activity.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                (time_1 = c(0.2500, 0.2501, 0.2499, 0.2500),
                (time_2 = c(0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5001, 0.5001),
                (time_3 = c(0.2501, 0.2499, 0.5001, 0.2498),
                (sum_time = c(1.0001, 1.0000, 1.0001, 0.9999))

  ID    time_1   time_2   time_3   sum_time
  1     0.2500   0.5000   0.2501   1.0001
  2     0.2501   0.5000   0.2499   1.0000
  3     0.2499   0.5001   0.5001   1.0001
  4     0.2500   0.5001   0.2498   0.9999
```

I intend to extract the compositional means of this data, however cannot do so if all of the values for `sum_time` do not exactly equal 1.

I have attempted to round to fewer decimal places using `round(data$time_1, digits = 3)` however this returns values of `0.999` and `1.001` in the instances that do not already equal 1.

I have also attempted to create a function whereby if the sum is either `1.0001` or `0.9999` then I subtract or add `0.0001` to one of the variables as the time difference in minutes is insignificant. However I cannot get these functions to work.

```
scale_compositions <- function(x){
  
if(df$sum_time== 1.0001) {df$time_1 - 0.0001}
if(df$sum_time == 0.9999) {df$time_1 + 0.0001}  
  
}

scale_compositions(x)
```

Ideally I would be able to rescale those variables that equal `1.0001` and `0.9999` such that each of the `time_` intervals is either increased or reduced by an appropriate amount to ensure the proportions displayed remain as accurate as possible but have been unable to figure this out so far. I have been playing around with the `rescale` functions in various R packages to no avail currently.

Given the insignificance of the `0.0001` to the overall time being investigated, it is unlikely that removing or adding that value to ensure every proportion is equal to 1 will meaningfully impact results (although this will be tested) and I am happy to do that for the time being.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could rescale each vector of `time_` intervals to sum to `1` without the conditionals. *ie* `rescaled_value = value/sum(value)`

Comment: `df[2:4] <- prop.table(df[2:4], 1)`. This scales your data and ensures that it sums to 1

Comment: If I were in your situation, I would follow @Seth's suggestion and renormalize the 3 time columns by dividing each by the value of `sum_time`. Are the values of your real data supposed to be in increments of a quarter of a whole number, as in your example? If so, you could also round each column to the nearest quarter, i.e. `round(time_1 / 0.25) * 0.25`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I haven't misunderstood your question but could this work?

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  time_1 = c(0.2500, 0.2501, 0.2499, 0.2500),
  time_2 = c(0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5001, 0.5001),
  time_3 = c(0.2501, 0.2499, 0.2500, 0.2498)
)

df$sum_time <- rowSums(df[, c("time_1", "time_2", "time_3")])
df$sum_time <- round(rowSums(df[, c("time_1", "time_2", "time_3")]), 3)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're after but to normalize you could divide by `rowSums` then recalculate sum_time which now sums to exactly 1.

```
> df[, 2:4] <- df[, 2:4]/rowSums(df[, 2:4])
> transform(df, sum_time=rowSums(df[, 2:4]))
  ID   time_1   time_2   time_3 sum_time
1  1 0.249975 0.499950 0.250075        1
2  2 0.250100 0.500000 0.249900        1
3  3 0.249925 0.249925 0.500150        1
4  4 0.250025 0.500150 0.249825        1
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4), time_1 = c(0.25, 0.2501, 0.2499, 
0.25), time_2 = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.2499, 0.5001), time_3 = c(0.2501, 
0.2499, 0.5001, 0.2498), sum_time = c(1.0001, 1, 1.0001, 0.9999
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```